# What is ColumnMapKeyPrune in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

**Getting error as `ERROR 2000: Error processing rule ColumnMapKeyPrune.` What could be the reason?**

Comment: what are you trying to achieve . pls share sample code, what have you done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a bug in pig. Try running with '-t ColumnMapKeyPrune' and see if it produces the expected output.  Sample code would help check if the issue is fixed on trunk or not.